# Error in load ASP.NET Core project (custom C# models are disabled, will not query for user from web service)

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 react project and I got this error when I'm trying to load the solution:

> [VSIX I] Trace log: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\VSFeedbackIntelliCodeLogs\20190719_051645_VS.log
>   [VSIX I] Version: 2.2.182.4985

and when the error in log file is:

> [2019-07-19 05:07:13.449 VSIX I] Version: 2.2.182.4985 [2019-07-19 05:07:13.465 CatalogManager V] Custom C# models are disabled, will not query for user from web service. [2019-07-19 05:07:13.465 Client V] IntelliCode User didn't resolve. Cannot query for custom models.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services)

Comment: @Syafiqur__ i'm using asp.net core application with react not ".NET FRAMEWORK" single page application